# Stream log data from CloudWatch

Tags: http, stream, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I can presumably get all log events from a CloudWatch logStream using:

```js
    const cwl = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs();

    cwl.getLogEvents({logGroupName, logStreamName}, (err, results) => {

      for (let r of results.events) {
        console.log(r.message);
      }

    });
```

however, my question is - is there a way to *stream* the logs instead of reading all of them at once? Seems like for some log streams there could be a million events/records so might be too much data to read all at once?

I looked at the declaration file for cloudwatchlogs.d.ts:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/clients/cloudwatchlogs.d.ts

don't see anything that can stream the logs to a client.

Comment: Have you checked this example using AWS Lambda: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html ? You can create a custom lambda function that is invoked by the log streams and where log processing / filtering can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can't stream it directly.

Responses from `getLogEvents` API contain `nextForwardToken` and `nextBackwardToken`. You can use those in subsequent requests to get the next batch of events if all of them could not have been returned in a single response. See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/get-log-events.html

Alternatively, you can use the `createExportTask` API to get the data into S3 and stream it from there. Not sure if the exported data will be in a streamable format. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/create-export-task.html